# Import Excel files to SQL Azure, within Azure

Tags: excel, azure, azure-sql-database, openxml, bcp

I have read questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483369/data-import-excel-to-sql-azure)(Is Jet.OLEDB supported in 64bit?) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352660/bulk-load-files-into-sql-azure) (requires on-premise MSSQL) in SSO, but I have not come across the right solution that suits me.

**I have some excel files (xlsx) in an Azure VM and I want to push all of these to the SQL Database in Azure. This would be a repetitive task, (files come in from a source and have to pushed to DB) - required to be executed on a daily basis.**

I am planning to use this approach -

**Current Solution** -

**Custom code**: A .NET app that uses OpenXML SDK/NPOI/EPPlus to read the files and manually push them to SQL Database (using .Net SQLBulkCopy). App runs within the VM.

The problem with the above approach is that - it requires time to code and test with excel files of varying schema. I am looking to see if there other options that could avoid custom code. Please note that there is no on-premise involvement here (So I presume no SSIS, no BCP(?) etc). This is not a one-time migration kind of activity.

**Other Options?**

1) **Access Database Engine?**: Can the "Access Database Engine" ([2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255) or [2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358)?) be used to get read the excel files rather than openXML or other tools? It appears to be an alternate to the Jet.OLEDB in a 64 bit environment. But I am unsure if this support excel 2007 formats as well and why would you choose this vs OpenXml SDK/NPOI/EPPlus if the job is just to read the excel file (no creation, manipulation)

2) **BCP in Azure?**: Can BCP used WITHIN azure? Not quite sure about this. If so, would it make sense to [convert](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246772/Convert-xlsx-xls-to-csv) XLSX to CSV and then use BCP to upload to SQL Database, thereby minimize the amount of code I have to write?

3) **ExcelDataReader?**: If custom code is the option, can the [ExcelDataReader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) which is cross-platform (and I don't need cross platform capability) and supports both XLS and XLSX. ExcelDataReader is said to be faster - but unsure how faster is it when compared to reading files using OpenXML SDK or tools like NPOI/EPPlus

Appreciate thoughts from the community.

Answer (score 1):

from my experiences, option 2 would be the most pragmatic.  It is a matter of preference/familiarity whether you want to open the Excel documents with a library like ExcelDataReader or programmatically convert the file first to CSV and read as a delimited file.  Either way, BCP is relatively straightforward way to get data into SQL Database using custom code.